# how to insert tex code in lyx shortcut?

Tags: lyx, shortcut

how can I insert "tex code" into a shortcut?

I'm trying to create a short cut for some tikz code and can't find how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command-sequence but a semi-colon is a special character for a command-sequence and there is no documented escape. This makes it difficult to, for example, insert a semi-colon, which is often useful for TikZ.

The following, for example, does not work as intended:

```
command-sequence preview-insert; ert-insert; self-insert \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1); \end{tikzpicture}
```

because the semicolon at the end of the `draw` command is not inserted. Instead, we can use LyX's `unicode-insert` as a workaround. I also add paragraph-breaks:

```
command-sequence preview-insert; ert-insert; self-insert \begin{tikzpicture}; paragraph-break; self-insert \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1); unicode-insert 0x003B; paragraph-break; self-insert \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a "tex code" box with the command:

```
ert-insert;
```

to insert the code itself you will use the command:

```
self-insert <code here>
```

for example:

if you try to create a shortcut for the beginning of the tikz code with the preview you can use the following code in your shortcut:

```
command-sequence preview-insert; ert-insert; self-insert \begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If you indent the line by four spaces, the line is turned into "code". See the edits.

Comment: ok. but how do I use semicolons (;) in shortcuts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the semicolons in your command-sequences seem to show up correctly.

Comment: I mean creating a shortcut for some tikz code with a semicolon at the end.
for example:
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);

Comment: ah, I see. You can use `unicode-insert` as a workaround. I added an answer with details. Feel free to incorporate the relevant part into your answer and I can delete my answer.